# Trouble getting user AND token in Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried testing a post request in Postman to create a user, but I keep getting errors in my controller when trying to create the user. I'm not getting my token at all. Here is my code.

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authorized, only: [:create]

  def create
    @user = User.create(user_params)
    if @user.valid?
      @token = encode_token(user_id: @user.id)
      render json: {
        @user => include: [:categories, :resources],
        jwt: @token
      }, status: :created
    else
      render json: { error: 'failed to create user' }, status: :not_acceptable
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

end
```

These are the errors I was getting:

SyntaxError (/Users/flatironschool/Desktop/5-Module/houston-helper-backend/app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected =>
      render json: => {
                   ^~
/Users/flatironschool/Desktop/5-Module/houston-helper-backend/app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
        @user => include: [:categories, :resources]
                        ^
/Users/flatironschool/Desktop/5-Module/houston-helper-backend/app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
      }, jwt: @token, status: :creat...
      ^):

app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected =>
app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end

Comment: can you please share the error message or console logs ??

Comment: Which are the errors that you are getting, can you show them in the code?

Comment: Are you using something like ActiveModel Serializer to serialize your model?

Comment: I added the errors. I am not using serializers this time. I just used " include: " instead. And I tried to fix the syntax errors one at a time, but it just gave me new syntax errors. I tried to look up the correct syntax for what I was writing, but I didn't find any examples that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is

```
{
    @user => include: [:categories, :resources],
    jwt: @token
  }
```

since its not a valid hash. Take a look at how to create [hashes in ruby](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html)!

I suggest to build your response step by step until you have what you need.
Start with

```
render json: @token
```

then you can try something like

```
render json: {user: @user.to_json, token: @token.to_json }
```

then whatever you want!

Comment: Actually it is a valid hash. Although its not used that often you can use any object as a hash key in ruby. Try `@hash = { foo: :bar }; { @hash => 'baz' }[@hash]` for example. So it is a valid ruby hash - its just not valid input for `render json:`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your code

```
render json: {
    @user => include: [:categories, :resources],
    jwt: @token
  }, status: :created
```

with

```
render json: {
    user: @user.as_json(include: [:categories, :resources]),
    jwt: @token
  }, status: :created
```

You can also use separate activemodel serializers if you want, however as_json is a built in serializer for activemodel objects provided by rails. You can learn more from [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json)

Hope this helps !